# User defined Value class giving compilation error

Tags: scala

I am defining a custom value class in a scala worksheet

```
class Dollars(val amount: Int) extends AnyVal {
  override def toString: String = "$" + amount
}
```

But, I am getting the following compilation error.

```
value class may not be a member of another class
```

I am using scala 2.12

Not sure what I am missing here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The error is quite explicit. The `Dollars` value class (`... extends AnyVal`) is defined inside another class, which is not possible for value class.

Comment: what's the other class in which Dollars is defined?

Comment: scala worksheet probably creates some wrapper class around your code.
Try it in REPL instead, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks guys, got it. It was the worksheet! Works fine in REPL.

Answer (score -4):

The problem is that your classes need to extend from AnyRef, not AnyVal. AnyRef is the Scala representation of Java's java.lang.Object.
For this same reason, you don't need to explicit this, as the following would suffice:

```
class Dollars(val amount: Int) {
  override def toString: String = "$" + amount
}
```

EDIT: Take a look at the Scala's class hierarchy: https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/71%3Fsize=_original.html#

Comment: I needed to create a AnyVal so that I can use if as any value type. and could do == and != kind of operations. By default AnyRef would have forced me to override hascode and equals method to do java style equals instead of == function.

Comment: Extending from AnyVal is possible. You might want to look up value classes.

Comment: @tintin And wouldn't case classes help you with that as they implement such methods by themselves?

Comment: The OP explicitly says he wants a Value Class. If it doesn't extend `AnyVal`, it's not a Value Class. Value Classes *must* extend `AnyVal`, that's how Scala *knows* it's a Value Class.